# Mapping Many-to-many tables with additional columns Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, orm, automapper

I have Users and Challenges table with many-to-many relationship. What I've been trying to do is to map these two tables. And I'm halfway succeeding as I am able to map  these two tables to get result:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "fullName": "test test",
    "username": "test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "abc123",
    "imgUrl": "",
    "points": 0,
    "level": 1,
    "usersChallenges": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Party Monster"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Do You Even Javascript?"
        }
    ]
}
```

But somehow I can't figure out how to **map additional columns** (`StartDate`,`EndDate`) to Users table. These are my entities:

```
public Challenges()
    {
        UsersChallenges = new HashSet<UsersChallenges>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int DaysNeeded { get; set; }
    public int Reward { get; set; }
    public byte Difficulty { get; set; }
    public int CompletedBy { get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public int Subcategory { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }

    public ChallengeCategories CategoryNavigation { get; set; }
    public ChallengeSubcategories SubcategoryNavigation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UsersChallenges> UsersChallenges { get; set; }
}



public partial class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        UsersChallenges = new HashSet<UsersChallenges>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UsersChallenges> UsersChallenges { get; set; }
}
```

Many-to-many:

```
public partial class UsersChallenges
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ChallengeId { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public Challenges Challenge { get; set; }
    public Users User { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<Users, UsersDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.UsersChallenges, 
            opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UsersChallenges
            .Select(y => y.Challenge).ToList()));
```

Comment: Map `StartDate` to what?

Comment: To each `UsersChallenges`

Comment: Then from what?

Comment: From `UsersChallenges` table

Comment: Huh? Can you give a before and after?

Comment: just use two one-to-many relationships if you'll require to access the join table anyways

Comment: Looks like your question has nothing in common with EF, since the model is correctly mapped to the database. The way I understand it, the issue is how to map entity classes to DTOs with AutoMapper. Hence in order to get help, please provide the relevant DTO classes.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro They already did that according to the shown entity model.